# Java: Convert excel value to a function name?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi

I have created an excel sheet called "TestCase.xls". I am picking up the values from each row and column. The 1st column contains the function name and the 2nd column contains the parameter to that function.
As i get data from my excel sheet, i get the values as Strings.
How do i convert those strings into functions names so that my java code could work on those functions.

Example: Testcase.xls

|enterSearchText|bikes|

Comment: [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) is your friend.

Comment: @kocko And your enemy as well :)

Comment: Haha, it can be if you overuse it :)

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun, congrats on 25K :)

Comment: Thanks my friend, it's rounded now.. I'm thinking about keeping it like that forever ;)

Answer (score 3):

Reflection is what you need.

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
Class classObj = c.getClass();
Method gs1Method = classObj.getMethod("enterSearchText", new Class[] {});
String str1 = (String) gs1Method.invoke(c, new Object[] {});
```

`invoke` will call a function that is passed as string. Assuming that MyClass has enterSearchText, the passed method will be passed. In order to pass something, to the function you can use below syntax.

```
String str1 = (String) gs1Method.invoke(c, new Object[] {"bikes"});
```

Comment: Its really nice... Though I don't have any such need right now but still its a good to learn these thing, very useful. Thanks.

Comment: The function is defined in abstract page, and function contains arguments.
It is showing java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: assignment.functions.enterSearchText()
I want to invoke method enterSearchText(String value)

Comment: I can't think of why it isn't working unless I see how you are trying to invoke. Please update your question with how you are doing now or post a new question.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly you want convert a string of numbers into an actual number so you can do operations with that number. If thats the case then you can use the .parse() method or if you have several numbers on the same string you can split it and save into an array. 
Here is how to use the parse method I think:
    int x = Integer.parse("4");
here is how to user split method:
    int[] y = new int[2];
    String z = "2,3";
    y = z.split(",");
here is your new array:
[2,3]
Hope this helped.

Comment: That is not what the question asked.